# Avoid precision loss in Convert process for float SQL

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, precision

I am trying to retain the float value in the column **coalesced_field_value** convert and coalesce SQL query. I am not able to do it.

I want the value as it is and no extra zero's 0

Any help is much appreciated here.

```
drop table #source
create table #source
(
    userid int NULL,
    fieldid int NULL,
    col1date date NULL,
    col3float float NULL,
    col3string nvarchar(4000) NULL,
)

insert into #source  
values (1,1,NULL,'1.3456786',NULL),
(1,1,NULL,'1.3456786789',NULL),
(1,2,'2020-01-01',NULL,NULL),
(2,1,NULL,NULL,'test')

select * from #source

select *,
    COALESCE(col3string, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), col1date),
    CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),  CAST(col3float AS decimal(18,14))))
    AS coalesced_field_value
FROM #source

userid  fieldid col1date      col3float         col3string   coalesced_field_value
1         1     NULL          1.3456786         NULL         1.34567860000000
1         1     NULL          1.3456786789      NULL         1.34567867890000
1         2     2020-01-01    NULL              NULL         2020-01-01
2         1     NULL          NULL              test         test
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string in SQL Server? Thats a front end/formatting job. You don't appear to have lost any precision as the title of your question says?

Comment: @DaleK this is to sync up between tables in the database. I want coalesced_field_value to be the same as col3float value. it adds extra 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing zeros are being added when you call CONVERT, since you are not passing a third parameter to CONVERT its using its default style for conversion between DECIMAL and VARCHAR.

CONVERT does not have the [specific style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you are looking for so rather cast the value with FORMAT which gives you direct control over the style string

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(col3string, 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), col1date),
       FORMAT(col3float,'0.####################')) AS coalesced_field_value
FROM #source
```